# git push -u origin master (ERROR)

Tags: html, windows, bash, git, github

I am trying to upload some of my projects to GitHub and I always see this error, you who think

[image]

Comment: When you have text output, don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Answer (score 1):

[git](/questions/tagged/git) tell you to *pull* modifications done by other(s), so :

```
git pull origin master
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

When this occurs. You usually have two options.

- Save the changes from `origin`, then push it again. In terminal, you do

  ```
  $ git pull origin master
  ```
- Not to care the changes of `origin`, so type:

  ```
  $ git push -u origin master --force
  ```

  Then git will perform a `force update`. So your commits from local will be pushed.

> In GitHub, this frequently happens if you both edit files in the remote and local. My suggestion is that if you use Git, you'd better not to use GitHub to edit files. Or you often need to force push